# Expected response code 354 but got an empty response - Error al enviar email laravel 7

Tags: laravel

Tengo un endpoint de una api donde recibo datos de registro de un usuario, en este endpoint recibo una direccion de correo del usuario donde debo enviar un email para su posterior confirmación pero no he podido realizar el envió, en mi función tengo:

```
try{
  $cliente->save(); //Guardo correctamente la información del cliente en la BD
  $details = [
    'title' => 'Mail from Laravel',
    'body' => 'This is for testing email using smtp'
  ];
  Mail::to($cliente->emailContacto)->send(new \App\Mail\RegisterClientMail($details));
  //Aquí debería enviar el email
}
catch(\Exception $e){
  return $e->getMessage();
} 

return response()->json([
            "success" => true,
            "message" => "Cliente creado exitosamente",
            "file" => $file
        ]);
```

El flujo nunca llega hasta el return final y tampoco marca algún tipo de error, solo me retorna la vista del email con status 200 pero no hace el envió del correo

```
{
  "data": "Expected response code 354 but got an empty response",
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK",
   .
   .
   .
  }
```

En RegisterClientMail.php tengo:

```
<?php

 namespace App\Mail;

 use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
 use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
 use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

 class RegisterClientMail extends Mailable
 {
  use Queueable, SerializesModels;

 /**
  * Create a new message instance.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function __construct($details)
  {
    //
    $this->details = $details;
  }

  /**
   * Build the message.
   *
   * @return $this
   */
  public function build()
  {
    return $this->subject('Se ha registrado como cliente')    
                ->view('emails.checkRegister');
    //return $this->view('view.name');
  }
}
```

En checkRegister.blade.php tengo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>ItsolutionStuff.com</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>{{ $details['title'] }}</h1>
  <p>{{ $details['body'] }}</p>
  <p>Thank you</p>
 </body>
```

En mi archivo .env tengo:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.host.co
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=user@dominio.co
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=""
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=user@dominio.co
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Alguien me podría indicar que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: tu servidor de correo esta dando una respuesta vacía ... puedes validar, no se si laravel tenga un modo debug ...

Comment: puedes validar si tu archivo config/mail.php tiene los datos correctos?

Comment: tambien debes ejecutar estos comandos: **php artisan config:clear**
y **php artisan config:cache**

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por responder, si en mi archivo config.mail.php tengo los mismos datos que en mi archivo .env, tambien ejecuto los comandos que mencionas y el error persiste, creo que es un error con la vista blade que se envia pero no doy con el problema

Comment: puedes hacer un `dd` del response luego de ejecutar el correo en lugar de enviarlo a la vista??

Comment: Es que no retorno una vista como tal, estoy trabajando en una api rest, la vista es la que se envia como cuerpo del correo electronico

Comment: entonces intenta mostrar la vista en lugar de enviarla como parte del correo ...

Comment: Si retorno la vista desde el metodo build de RegisterMail.php el response es: "Invalid view.'"

Comment: entonces hay existe un indicio; pero fácilmente ese texto puede ser el cuerpo del correo ... y el correo debería de ejecutarse tranquilamente ...asique no se lo llego a atribuir del todo ...

Comment: Intente meter la vista como un string de esta forma : Mail::to($cliente->emailContacto)->send("<html><body><h1>Hello</h1></body></html>");    
     pero al hacerlo da error 500

Comment: por que eso esta mal planteado ... cual es el contenido de $cliente->emailContacto

Comment: $cliente->emailContacto es la direccion de correo a la que le debe llegar el email

Comment: yo se que es; no he preguntado que es; pregunte que contiene ...

Comment: Contiene una dirección de correo que recibo desde el cliente, verifique con un dd() y la dirección es correcta

Comment: ok entonces no se que pueda estar saliendo mal ...